# Texture Inflating in Parts of Mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, shaders

I'm working on a mesh and I applied a displacement node, however around the arms and legs the texture gets significantly larger. How do I make the texture the same size everywhere?[image]

Comment: You can try using the generated or object coordinates instead of the UVs

Answer (score 1):

Your texture is getting stretched. What you want to do is to go into the UV tab, go into edit mode in the other window, and select the stretched faces. Then, you want to go into the UV workspace, go to the top where it says 'New' and 'Open', and click the picture icon next to that. Click on the texture in the dropdown menu, and the texture should pop up. You should see the selected faces un the UV editor. Scale them up, and that should shrink your texture.